# at/on/in occasions

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

What's the right explanation?

We wear our best clothes at happy occasions such as parties and festivals.
My question:

Why do we say “***at*** happy occasions” and not, say, “***on***” or “***in*** happy occasions”?

Comment: Check dictionaries and study examples given there. It's *on occasions.* Why? Because it's like that..you need to learn like that.

Comment: There's no fixed rule about which preposition to use here, but I'd be prepared to bet money most native speakers would actually favour ***for*** over ***at*** or ***on*** (and ***in*** would be *very* unlikely).

Comment: @FF This may represent a difference between US English and British English. "On the occasion of" is actually more common in American English. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+the+occasion+of%2C+for+the+occasion+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20the%20occasion%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfor%20the%20occasion%20of%3B%2Cc0I am not sure I can articulate when one preposition seems appropriate to me and when the other does, but I do not use them interchangeably. So I would not close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't say that - we say "*on* occasions".

However, we do say "*at*" parties and festivals, so perhaps this is where your confusion has come in? You've said that parties and festivals are "occasions", which they are.

You could perhaps switch it around and say:

> We wear our best clothes at parties, festivals, and other happy occasions.

Answer (score -2):

The writer probably meant to say "at happy events," or was confusing it with that phrase. Whether the usage is technically acceptable can be a subject of debate, but it's not standard.

Comment: We would say _at parties_, but _on happy occasions_. Maybe the writer had second thoughts about the sentence, but forgot to edit it properly.

Comment: @Kate Bunting Exactly.

Comment: Can we say, we wear our best clothes on happy occasions such as parties...